# Re-continuing reading the Qu'ran: should I continue or restart?

Tags: quran

I was reading Qur'an at a time then I stopped. Now after some months, I want to start reading again but I want to start from the beginning. Can I start from the beginning again or should I continue from where I stopped?

Comment: Its your wish but i think you should begin from the starting since Jibreel (peace be upon him ) revised the entire  Quran this month with the Prophet  (peace be upon him )

Answer (score 3):

There is no restriction or fix rule, you could start at the verse you stopped from to complete a recitation (khatmah) -which is a recommended act according to [sunnah](http://sunnah.com/urn/731940)- or restart from the fatiha.

On the other hand it is not recommended to start two or more parallel khatmah!

And keep in mind:

> Narrated Muhammad bin Ka'b Al-Qurazi:
> "I heard 'Abdullah bin Mas'ud saying: 'The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "[Whoever recites a letter] from Allah's Book, then he receives the reward from it, and the reward of ten the like of it. I do not say that Alif Lam Mim is a letter, but Alif is a letter, Lam is a letter and Mim is a letter." ([Jami' at-Tirmidhi](http://sunnah.com/urn/731520))

This is the statement of [this fatwa](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/128050).

And Allah knows best!

Comment: JazakAllah for sharing that hadith which is hidden in Sunnah ,I have not read it before.